# Display my image from a map() with a bigger size when i click on it

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

I am currently displaying a .map of an image object array.

I would like to know how to display this preview in a larger size when I click on the image.

Here is the function that maps my images.

```
        return (
            <div className="tools" data-toggle="tooltip" style={{position: "absolute",top: "57%",left: "45%",maxWidth: "100%", height: "auto", zIndex: "2"}}>
                {one.map(ones => (
                    <img className="thumb" style={{width: "150px"}} key={ones.image} onClick={() => setIsPop(true)}  src={ones.image} alt={ones.image}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I'd like to be able to see the same picture bigger when I click on it.

Comment: depends on how u want to show..like pop up... of just make it bigger.

Comment: i would like to show it in a popup

Comment: then create a popup component and on click, pass the URL to popup component